# Unable to use Exoplayer lib in android

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to implement `Exoplayer` in android to stream songs. This is what I have tried until now by following this [link](http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:android_minimal_exoplayer_use:txt)

I have 2 buttons in my layout file, 1 to start player and other to stop.

Here is the class file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button btPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_play);
    Button btStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_stop);
    Context mContext = getBaseContext();
    String URL = "http://sound15.mp3slash.net/indian/tummile/tummile01(www.songs.pk).mp3";

    btPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
            final int numRenderers = 2;
            SampleSource sampleSource = new FrameworkSampleSource(mContext, uri, null, numRenderers);
//above line gives me error

            TrackRenderer audioTrack = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

            ExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(numRenderers);
            exoPlayer.prepare(audioTrack);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    });

}
```

The error thrown is on SampleSource line which says

> cannot resolve constructor FrameworkSampleSource

How do I deal with this error and carry on to stream song. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

for using library in appropriate way:
[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WBVsEYg1mg)

FrameworkSampleSource is depreciated use ExtractorSampleSource

see below code:

```
        String url = parentArray.getJSONObject(songIndex).getString("file");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1);
        playerControl = new PlayerControl(player);
        DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, TAG);
        ExtractorSampleSource extractorSampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri, dataSource, new DefaultAllocator(64 * 1024), 64 * 1024 * 256);
        audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(extractorSampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
        player.prepare(audioRenderer);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: It still gives me same error!! I am not getting why is that so!

Comment: [link](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/d4dcabcdc73a391f25743408affc2f9f20160330065928/c996c184fc51f4d05f88091a70a7279920160330065928/ab3e89) download code